# java - Socket Stream

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sockets, network-programming

i want to get text from stream . but i dont get it correctly  .

Everything works good , but i only need to know how to get PrintWriter into string .

i tried to convert PrintWriter with the function .ToString()  but it doesnt work correctly  ,  is print differen string .

Java :

```
private ServerSocket Server_Socket;

private static final int CLIENTRPORT = 5000;

Socket socket = null;

class Connect_To_Client implements Runnable
 {
  @Override
  public void run()
   {
    try
     {
      Server_Socket = new ServerSocket(CLIENTRPORT);
      socket = Server_Socket.accept();
     }
    catch (IOException e)
     {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
}

public BufferedReader input;

public String Get_Message_From_Server()
 {   
  PrintWriter out = null;
  String out_string = "";

  try
   {
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println(input);
   }
  catch (IOException e)
   {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
  return(out_string);//the text - problem
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To read from a buffered reader do something like this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
       sb.append(line);
       line = reader.readLine();
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: That's close, but you are stripping out the new lines chars this way.

Comment: This is true, appending a '\n' character after the line would be an option in this case.